# How to determine minimum system requirements

Tags: windows, deployment, requirements

How do you decide what the minimum system requirements are for a Windows application? (OS, RAM, HD, CPU). I usually go with my gut, but I'd like to be able to back that up with something.

Answer (score 2):

> On the same note, are there tools
>   available to artifically limit CPU
>   speed and RAM? I'd like to be able to
>   slow a test computer down, rather than
>   acquire a system with an antequated
>   CPU.

The second part of your question is answered in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284051/emulate-old-pc#284108).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm just going to delete that second part, since I would have closed as dupe if that was the only questions.

Comment: It isn't the only question -- so it's not really a dupe, but I'd maintain the two questions and simply edit your question to say, "Hey, the second part was answered here")

Answer (score 1):

Your minimum system requirements are the highest requirements of the set of system requirements of your dependencies.

Comment: Doesn't that assume that my app basically doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Jon, not if you have requirements that say "the system shall do X in Y seconds".

Comment: If you have performance-based requirements, you're going to need to do performance testing.  If "minimum requirements" means "the app will successfully load and run, eventually" then what I said tends to be a pretty good rough estimate.