# How can I simulate a very slow computing environment?

Tags: environment, emulation

Is there some emulator out there where I can program in some language (C, C++, Assembly etc.) and where I can slow down the Hz rate (down to 1MHz or something)

I've been very curious how difficult it is to program with such a limitation and wondering if there is a software solution to this before I go out to buy a chip.

Comment: Do you literally mean slow as in clock speed, or is that just an example of a slow environment? If you just want a qualitatively 'slow' environment, why not just just remove all but 512MB RAM from your Windows 7 box?!

Comment: is this a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284051/emulate-old-pc ?